# Scala parser combinator reduce/foldLeft

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I'm trying to make the following, from a dynamically filled List:

```
val primitives = "x" | "y" | "z" // what I want

val primitives2 = List("x", "y", "z") // what I need to transform from
```

I figured something like this might work:

```
primitives2.reduce(_|_)
```

But no go. I then found this snippet, which works:

```
primitives2.foldRight(failure("no matching delimiter"): Parser[Any])(_|_)
```

However, the base case `failure("no matching delimiter")` is confusing. Is that just the equivalent Nil case for Parser objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're working with `RegexParsers` or one of its descendants. If so, then the issue is just that the implicit conversion from `String` to `Parser[String]` won't kick in automatically with `reduce(_ | _)`. If you explicitly convert every item in your list first, like this:

```
val anyPrimitive = primitives2.map(literal).reduce(_ | _)
```

You'll be perfectly fine—except that this will leave you with slightly confusing error messages, like this:

```
scala> parser.parseAll(parser.anyPrimitive, "a")
res8: parser.ParseResult[Any] = 
[1.1] failure: `z' expected but `a' found

a
^
```

If you want a clearer error message, then you'll need to provide your own starting value using the `fold` approach.